# What are the miminal required environments for a KOMA-Script scrlttr2?

Tags: koma-script, examples, invoice

I want to use the KOMA-Script letter2 class for creating client invoices.  I've read the user guide (version 2017-08-08) and searched the web without finding the answer.

The only way I can get the draft to compile with pdflatex (within LyX) is by including the environments such as opening, closing, signature, and a couple of others. In the preamble I include the invoice2 package which has 'customer' and 'invoice no.' environments and I want to learn how to use the invoice2 package for invoicing and sending statements. So I want to find the fewest required environments to produce an invoice using the scrlttr2 class. Are there examples available?

Comment: No way to answer your question without an example or a minimal working example. You can make LyX export LaTeX code.

Comment: Rather difficult to add a minimal example when I I don't know how few environments must be included. What I want are: logo, date, client name and address, project name and number, and invoice number. Then a table with rows for each activity being invoiced.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of examples for letters with `scrlttr2` in the [KOMA-Script manual](https://komascript.de/scrguien), starting with the most simple in section 4.7, "General Structure of Letter Documents":

```
\documentclass[version=last]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Joana Public\\
Hillside 1\\
12345 Public-City}
\opening{Dear chairman,}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image: simple letter]

(`\opening` is needed to get the elements of the first letter page, like letter head, addressee and fold marks); until a more complex one in section 4.20, "Closing":

```
\documentclass[foldmarks=true,foldmarks=blmtP,
fromphone,fromemail,fromlogo,
subject=titled,
version=last]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphics}
\begin{document}
\setkomavar{fromname}{John Public}
\setkomavar{signature}{John Public\\
(former chairman)}
\renewcommand*{\raggedsignature}{\raggedright}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Valley 2\\
54321 Public-Village}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{0\,12\,34~56\,78}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{Peter@Public.invalid}
\setkomavar{fromlogo}{\includegraphics{musterlogo}}
\setkomavar{location}{\raggedright
Club nember no.~4711\\
since 11.09.2001\\
chairman 2003--2005}
\setkomavar{date}{29th February 2011}
\setkomavar{place}{Public-Village}
\setkomavar{subject}{Missing general meeting}
\begin{letter}{%
Joana Public\\
Hillside 1\\
12345 Public-City%
}
\opening{Dear chairman,}
the last general meeting was about one year ago.
I want to remind you, that the constitution of our
club advises you to make a general meeting every
six month. Because of this I expect the executive
board to detain such a meeting immediately.
\closing{Expecting an invitation}
\ps PS: I hope you accept this as an friendly
demand note.
\setkomavar*{enclseparator}{Enclosure}
\encl{Compendium of the constitution with the
general meeting paragraphs.}
\cc{executive board\\all members}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image: more complex letter]

For individual designs you can find additional examples in the [KOMA-Script documentation project](https://komascript.de). There are not only German examples but also some in English like: [Reproducing the official header of the Washington State University](https://komascript.de/node/1599).

The German KOMA-Script book has additional, interesting [examples](https://komascript.de/komascriptbuch5examples) for "modern letters" (appendix/Anhang D). One of it results in:

[image: modern letter]

If you want to use, class `scrlttr2` (or package `scrletter`) for invoices, you should start with a letter, add, e.g., `\setkomavar{title}{Invoice}` and think about the reference line fields you need, e.g., `customer`. We currently do not know, what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Here a link for [examples available](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/admin/html/scrlttr2.shtml).

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\usepackage[british]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Dott. Yuko Ono\\24 Street Canvas\\Last Village\\
Some Town\\Noshire\\AB1 2YZ}
  \opening{Dear Mrs~Canary}

  This is an imaginary letter.

  This is the second paragraph of the letter.

  \closing{Yours sincerely}

  \ps PS: this is a postscript.

  \encl{Photocopy of something interesting\\
   Photocopy of something rather dull}

  \cc{Prof Important Person\\
   Dr Bor Ing}
\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have looked multiple times at the examples. They all have an opening, closing, and signature. I've not been able to compile a letter without these. That's why I'm asking what environments _must_ be in a letter.