# Problems with fillable PDFs

Tags: koma-script, letters, scrlttr2

I am trying to create a writable pdf and I took a cue from here:
[Creating fillable PDFs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14842/creating-fillable-pdfs) and [What are the miminal required environments for a KOMA-Script scrlttr2?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403077/what-are-the-miminal-required-environments-for-a-koma-script-scrlttr2)

I don't understand how to arrange things well so that it is easy and intuitive for those who have to use it.
The code I am using is definitely not correct.
would you have any suggestions?

```
\documentclass[%
  fontsize=11pt,
  parskip=half,%%
% fromalign=right,% right,locationright %% <============================
  firsthead=true, % <===================================================
  fromphone=on,%%
  fromfax=on,%%
  fromrule=aftername,%%
  fromemail=on,%%
  fromlogo=true,%%
  foldmarks=false,%%
  firstfoot=false,%%
  subject=titled,%%
  pagenumber=botright,%%
  headsepline=true, % <=================================================
  DIN
]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian,english]{babel}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{newcent}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{selinput}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\date{} %% elimina la data

\setkomafont{fromname}{\scshape \LARGE}
\setkomafont{backaddress}{\mdseries}

\makeatletter
\@setplength{firstheadvpos}{7mm}
\@setplength{firstfootvpos}{265mm}%%
\makeatother
\setkomavar{firsthead}{\raggedleft % <==================================
  \usekomavar{fromlogo}\\[+1cm]
  \rule{\textwidth}{0.5pt}\\
  \usekomavar{fromaddress}\\
  \usekomavar{fromphone}\\
  \usekomavar{fromfax}\\
  \usekomavar{fromemail}\\% <===========================================
}

\newdimen\longline
\longline=\textwidth\advance\longline-10cm

\def\LayoutTextField#1#2{#2} % override default in hyperref

\def\lbl#1{\hbox to 0.2cm{#1\strut}}%
\def\labelline#1#2{\lbl{#1}\vbox{\hbox{\TextField[name=#1,width=#2,bordercolor={white}, backgroundcolor={white}]{}}\kern1pt\hrule}}

\def\q#1{\hbox to \hsize{\labelline{#1}{\longline}}}
\def\qq#1{\hbox to \hsize{\labelline{#1}{\longlinee}}}


\begin{document}
%--------------------------------------
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{
    address\\
    Street}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{Tel: +99\,999\,99\,99\,99}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{mail:email@blabla.com}
\setkomavar{backaddressseparator}{ - }
\setkomavar{fromlogo}{\includegraphics[scale=.5]{logos}\vspace{-1.3cm}}

\setkomavar{subject}{
money refund request}

%------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{letter}{}
\opening{}
%\def\DefaultHeightofText{12pt}
%
\begin{Form} %%%%%??????
 Il/La Sig. \q nato/a \q il \q residente in \q Via \q, C.F:\q, in qualità di....
\end{Form}

\begin{Form}
 \mbox{\CheckBox[width=10pt,height=10pt,bordercolor=0 0 0,name=pri]{\ignorespaces}} {legal tutor} \par\\
 \end{Form}

 \begin{Form}
 \mbox{\CheckBox[width=10pt,height=10pt,bordercolor=0 0 0,name=sec]{\ignorespaces}} {family of reference} \par\\
\end{Form}

\begin{Form}
\mbox{\CheckBox[width=10pt,height=10pt,bordercolor=0 0 0,name=ter]{\ignorespaces}} {The reimbursement of expenses will be made in the name of\q
resident in \q, CF:\q } \par\\
\end{Form}    

%  \opening{Dear Mr. xxxxx xxxxxxxxxx,}
% %
%  \lipsum[1-8]
% %
%  \closing{Regards,}
% \setkomavar*{enclseparator}{Enclosure(s)}
%
% \encl{example enclosure}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: there should be only one Form environment by document (actually it should be enough to simply use \Form at the begin). And don't use `\def` until you really know what you are doing. Use \newcommand or \renewcommand instead.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, thanks for the reply, but i can't find the solution. I'm also looking for examples but they all refer to Forms. what I'm doing is a request form so it should be written as if it were a letter.

Comment: My comments weren't meant as solution,  only as remarks about wrong code in your example.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer To my great regret, I was unable to conclude this topic, perhaps it does not arouse interest. I have tried to do research but I have not found and according to your suggestion, maybe I am not very good.

Comment: well to my liking your question is too long and seems to ask to many questions at once.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer sorry for the delay in answering, I am a caregiver and I take care of my mother and I have difficulty being quick to answer.

briefly I would like to understand how to create a pdf that can be compiled with LaTex without having to use other software such as acrobat or other. for me it is a new approach and I do not deny having a lot of difficulty in this regard